# Redirect log4j console output to remote log server

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rsyslog

I'm managing a Stand-alone Java application which uses log4j facility to handle logging. I need to redirect its output to remote Rsyslog server. I configured log4j.properties files, but I can't restart this application, due to it's a mission-critical application.

Is there any way which I could redirect log to rsyslog without restart this java application?

Comment: log4j.properties is usually not a hot-pick one. If your app is running on a cluster (i.e. weblogic cluster) you may perform a rolling bounce. Otherwise   you'll have to wait for next major release? Worst case you can write a temporary application which listens to log files and write them on rsyslog

Comment: What version of log4j do you use?

Comment: thank your for info. Do you any other logging facility which acts differently, I mean I could change its configuration on the fly?